# Presented with TemplateDoesNotExist error

Tags: python, django, visual-web-developer

I have made two files

market.py
crypto.html

The code in market py draws data from two API addresses and it is supposed to show them in crypto.html when I run the server and try to open crypto.html I'm presented with TemplateDoesNotExist at /crypto/

as other posts on sof have explained I tried to tinker with INSTALLED_APPS = [
however I cannot get the page to function.

market.py

```
import requests, time
from django.shortcuts import render


class CryptoData:
   def __init__(self):
    self.usd_url = "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?" \
               "vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=250&page=1" 
\
               "&sparkline=false&price_change_percentage=24h"
self.gbp_url = "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?" \
               "vs_currency=gbp&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=250&page=1" 
\
               "&sparkline=false&price_change_percentage=24h"

self.previous_request = None
self.results1 = None
self.results2 = None

def get_crypto_data_dict(self, seconds_to_wait=60):
crypto_dict = dict()
if not self.previous_request or self.previous_request + seconds_to_wait < 
time.time():
    print("requested", self.previous_request, time.time())
    self.previous_request = time.time()
    crypto_dict = dict()
    requests1 = requests.get(self.usd_url)
    self.results1 = requests1.json()

    requests2 = requests.get(self.gbp_url)
    self.results2 = requests2.json()

for i in range(0, 250):
    crypto_dict[self.results1[i]['id']] = {
        'coin_name': self.results1[i]['name'],
        'changes': self.results1[i]['price_change_percentage_24h'],
        'usd': self.results1[i]['current_price'],
        'gbp': self.results2[i]['current_price']
    }

return crypto_dict


crypto_data = CryptoData()


def crypt_view(request):
context = {
    'crypto_data': crypto_data.get_crypto_data_dict()
}

return render(request, 'crypto.html', context=context)
```

crypto.html

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <ul>
         {% for crypto_datum, crypto_value in crypto_data.items %}
            <li>{{ crypto_datum }}
                <ul>

                    {% for info, value in crypto_value.items %}
                        <li>{{ info }}: {{ value }}</li>
                    {% endfor %}


                </ul>

            </li>
         {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endblock content %}
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, CreateView

from coinGecko import market
from .models import Post


def home(request):
context = {
    'posts': Post.objects.all()
}
return render(request, 'blog/home.html', context)


class PostListView(ListView):
model = Post
template_name = 'blog/home.html'
context_object_name = 'posts'
ordering = ['-date_posted']


class PostDetailView(DetailView):
model = Post


class PostCreateView(CreateView):
model = Post
fields = ['title', 'content']

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.author = self.request.user
    return super().form_valid(form)


def about(request):
return render(request, 'blog/about.html', {'title': 'About'})

def crypt_view(request):
cryto_data = market.CryptoData

context = {
    'crypto_data': market.crypto_data.get_crypto_data_dict()
}

return render(request, 'coinGecko/crypto.html', context=context)
```

I had tested the market.py and it was displaying the correct data when I set it to print out each line. I was able to view it in cmd output.

I know the code works but I think the problem now is getting market.py to output the data to crypto.html

Current output when crypto.html is opened:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /crypto/
coinGecko/crypto.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/crypto/
Django Version: 2.1.5
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
coinGecko/crypto.html
Exception Location:  
C:\Users\Ace\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site- 
packages\django\template\loader.py in get_template, line 19
Python Executable:                          
C:\Users\Ace\Desktop\django_project\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.2
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\Ace\\Desktop\\django_project',
'C:\\Users\\Ace\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\python37.zip',
'C:\\Users\\Ace\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\DLLs',
'C:\\Users\\Ace\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib',
'C:\\Users\\Ace\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37',
'C:\\Users\\Ace\\Desktop\\django_project\\venv',
'C:\\Users\\Ace\\Desktop\\django_project\\venv\\lib\\site-packages',
'C:\\Users\\Ace\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python37\\site-packages',
'C:\\Users\\Ace\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site- 
packages']
Server time:    Sun, 3 Feb 2019 20:35:00 +0000enter code here
```

Traceback:

```
Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/crypto/

Django Version: 2.1.5
Python Version: 3.7.2
Installed Applications:
['blog.apps.BlogConfig',
'users.apps.UsersConfig',
'crispy_forms',
'coinGecko',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']

 Template loader postmortem
 Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

 Using engine django: 
 * django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:


 C:\Users\Ace\Desktop\django_project\blog\
 templates\blog\coinGecko\crypto.html 
 (Source does not exist)
 * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: 
 C:\Users\Ace\Desktop\django_project\blog\templates\coinGecko\crypto.html 
 (Source does not exist)
 * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: 
 C:\Users\Ace\Desktop\django_project\users\templates\coinGecko\crypto.html 
 (Source does not exist)
 * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: 
 C:\Users\Ace\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site- 
 packages\crispy_forms\templates\coinGecko\crypto.html (Source does not 
 exist)
 * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: 
 C:\Users\Ace\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site- 
 packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\coinGecko\crypto.html (Source     
 does not exist)
 * django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: 
 C:\Users\Ace\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site- 
 packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\coinGecko\crypto.html (Source does 
 not exist)

 File "C:\Users\Ace\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site- 
 packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
 34.             response = get_response(request)

 File "C:\Users\Ace\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site- 
 packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
 126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, 
 request)

 File "C:\Users\Ace\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site- 
 packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
 124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, 
 **callback_kwargs)

 File "C:\Users\Ace\Desktop\django_project\blog\views.py" in crypt_view
 46.     return render(request, 'coinGecko/crypto.html', context=context)

 File "C:\Users\Ace\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site- 
 packages\django\shortcuts.py" in render
 36.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context,   
 request, using=using)

 File "C:\Users\Ace\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site- 
 packages\django\template\loader.py" in render_to_string
 61.         template = get_template(template_name, using=using)

 File "C:\Users\Ace\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site- 
 packages\django\template\loader.py" in get_template
 19.     raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)

 Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist at /crypto/
 Exception Value: coinGecko/crypto.html
```

Templates:

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [r'C:\Users\Ace\Desktop\django_project\blog\templates\blog'],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
           ],
        },
    },
]
```

The file structure leading to crypto.html

```
 DjangoProject
      /blog
         /templates
            /blog
              /about.html
              /base.html
              /home.html
      /coinGecko
         /crypto.html
         /market.py
```

Comment: Post the whole error message with traceback please.

Comment: Where is the `crypto.html` in your file structure, and what is your `TEMPLATES` setting?

Comment: I have edited the post to add traceback.

Comment: Your template directory path is `'DIRS': [r'C:\Users\Ace\Desktop\django_project\blog\templates\blog'],` and your html is in `C:\Users\Ace\Desktop\django_project\coinGecko\..`. And also don't write the whole path in DIRS, you can refer it from BASE_DIR

Comment: @BidhanMajhi how would refer it from BASE_DIR thanks

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. I agree with everything @BidhanMajhi said - but the quickest fix for now would simply be to put a `templates` directory inside `/coinGecko`, with a subdirectory called `coinGecko`, and the `crypto.html` inside that. That's basic good practice anyway, and matches what you've done in your `blog` app.